# Why does this code for shifting left in a 2D array not work and shifts left 2 instead?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

This code is to shift a 2D array "arr" to the left completely once it runs through, but for some reason, the elements are shifting over by two.

```
public static void shiftLeft()
        {
        for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)
        {
            int temp = arr[i][0];
            int n = 0;
            for(n = 0;n<arr.length - 1;n++)
            {

                arr[i][n] = arr[i][n+1];

                arr[i][n+1] = temp;


            }
        } 
    }
```

Comment: Do you use Eclipse to code? Did you try debugging? Also, what's the expected vs actual output? What do you expect [ [2, 4, 6], [1, 3, 5] ] to give you?

Comment: The expected output from 

1 3 4 2

would be

3 4 2 1

Answer (score 0):

It's not left shifting two times.  Your `for` loops are set up wrongly.

What you want to do is to have the outer `for loop` loop through the rows, and the inner `for loop` loop through the row elements (columns)

```
--> outer loop [ .... ]
               [ .... ]
                 |
                 v
              inner loop
```

In your case, both the for loops are iterating over `arr.length`, which in case of 2D array is number of rows.  You'd want your inner loop to loop `arr[0].length - 1` number of times.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
for(int i = 0; i<arr.length;i++)
{

    int temp = arr[i][0];
    int n = 0;
    for(n = 0;n<arr[i].length - 1;n++)//This line has been changed
    {

        arr[i][n] = arr[i][n+1];

        arr[i][n+1] = temp;


    }
}
```